# How to calculate days between multiple dates in mysql and php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have table in mysql which contain `start_date`, `end_date` and `id` like this

```
start_date   end_date     id
---------------------------------------------
2018-01-01   2018-01-01   5
2018-01-03   2018-01-03   5
2018-01-03   2018-01-08   5
2018-01-06   2018-01-07   7
2018-01-07   2018-01-07   7
2018-01-09   2018-01-11   7
2018-01-02   2018-01-02   8
2018-01-02   2018-01-04   8
2018-01-08   2018-01-08   9
```

I want output in mysql for total number of days for id like.

```
total_days  id
-------------------------
7          5
5          7
3          8
1          9
```

There is day gap between dates of particular ids. Please check start and end dates of each id. I think it need to put all dates in one sequence and then calculate days from first to next. I don't know how to do it. `2018-01-08`  to `2018-01-08` should be one day. `2018-01-08` to `2018-01-09` should be 2 days but not 1.
Please help.
Program is developing in php..

Comment: Select DATEDIFF(start_date, end_date);

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: And don't forget to identify your primary key

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution that it is not possible in hardcore mysql. I need to do using programming language. As I developed my software using PHP, So I calculated days using PHP code. I align-sort all dates one by other and then calculate days between each date. 
Thanks for all who gave answers to my question.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the DATEDIFF function:

*MS SQL SERVER:*

```
SELECT id, sum(DATEDIFF(day, startdate, enddate) +1) FROM table group by id;
```

*MYSQL:*

```
SELECT id, DATEDIFF(max(enddate), min(startdate)) + 1 FROM demo group by id;
```

Demo Fiddle: [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4583f5/5)

Datediff documentation MS SQL Server : [MS SQL SERVER Datediff](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Datediff documentation MYSQL : [MYSQL Datediff](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)

Comment: But this function only calculating start to end days. There are duplicate dates in row. So days will become duplicate.

Comment: @BahirjiNaik you are doing something wrong then... Look at the demo fiddle I put in my answer

Comment: DATEDIFF(day, start_date, end_date)  is sqlserver, mysql equivalent is DATEDIFF(start_date, end_date)

Comment: Thanks for help.. but this query is getting fail when there is difference of more than 1 day. Means when there is empty days more than 2.

Comment: @BahirjiNaik what do you mean by that and can you give an example of what you are saying

Comment: Change data for id 8 for 2 rows.

start_date1 : `2018-01-02`  end_date1 :  `2018-01-02`
start_date2 : `2018-01-06`  end_date2 :  `2018-01-06`

What will be the result now ?

Comment: @Bahirji Naik 5 days ,what do you think it should be?

Answer (score 1):

DateDiff function supports minus and plus in output:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(start_date, end_date) + 1
```

Comment: See.. as this table contain duplicate dates in `start_date` number of days will become duplicate.

Comment: You can not find date overlaps using pure sql

Answer (score 0):

**select distinct id,count(start_date-end_date) as "total_days" from table_name**

Comment: See.. as this table contain duplicate dates in `start_date` number of days will become duplicate.

Comment: you could add some clarification

Comment: IF u check, dates are getting overlapped. It will get overlapped days.